# Regex to exclude an entire line match if certain characters found

Tags: javascript, regex, greasemonkey, tampermonkey

I'm stuck on the cleanest way to accomplish two bits of regex.  Every solution I've come up with so far seems clunky.

Example text

```
Match:    Choose: blah blah blah 123 for 100'ish characters, this matches

NoMatch:  Choose: blah blah blah 123! for 100'ish characters?, .this potential match fails for the ! ? and .
```

---

The first regex `(?:^\w+?:)(((?![.!?]).)*)$` needs to:

- Match a line containing any `word` followed by a `:` so long as `!?.` are not found in the same line (the `word:` will always be at the beginning of a line)
- Ideally, match every part of the line from the example EXCEPT `Choose:`.  Matching the whole line is still a win.

The second regex `^(^\w+?:)(?:(?![.!?]).)*$` needs to:

- Match a line containing any `word` followed by a `:` so long as `!?.` are not found in the same line (the `word:` will always be at the beginning of a line)
- Match only `Choose:`

The regex is in a greasemonkey/tampermonkey script.

Comment: Do you mean like this? `^\w+:(?!.*[!?.])` https://regex101.com/r/D9EBRE/1 or `^\w+:(?![^!?.\n\r]*[!?.])`

Comment: I would go with simple `/^(\w+:)\s*([^.!?]*)$/`

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
^\w+:(?:(?!.*[.!?])(.*))?
```

See [proof](https://regex101.com/r/hILSmM/1).

**EXPLANATION**

```
NODE                     EXPLANATION
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  ^                        the beginning of the string
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \w+                      word characters (a-z, A-Z, 0-9, _) (1 or
                           more times (matching the most amount
                           possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  :                        ':'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?:                      group, but do not capture (optional
                           (matching the most amount possible)):
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    (?!                      look ahead to see if there is not:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
      .*                       any character except \n (0 or more
                               times (matching the most amount
                               possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
      [.!?]                    any character of: '.', '!', '?'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    )                        end of look-ahead
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    (                        group and capture to \1:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
      .*                       any character except \n (0 or more
                               times (matching the most amount
                               possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    )                        end of \1
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )?                       end of grouping
```

Answer (score 0):

Does this do what you want?

```
(?:^\w+:)((?:(?![!?.]).)*)$
```

What makes you feel that this is clunky?

```
    (?: ... )  non-capturing group
    ^          start with
    \w+:       a series of one or more word characters followed by a :
    ( ... )$   capturing group that continues to the end
    (?: ... )* non-capturing group, repeated zero or more times, with
    (?! ... )  negative look-ahead: no following character can be
    [!?.]      either ?, ! or .
    .          followed by any character
```

Comment: `((?![!?.]).)*` is a very inefficient way of saying `[^!?.]*` (the only difference is that the latter also matches line breaks, which might even be an advantage).

Answer (score 0):

For the first pattern, you could first check that there is no `!` `?` or `.` present using a negative lookahead. Then capture in the first group 1+ word chars and `:` and the rest of the line in group 2.

```
^(?![^!?.\n\r]*[!?.])(\w+:)(.*)$
```

- `^` Start of string
- `(?!` Negative lookahead, assert what is on the right is not

  - `[^!?.\n\r]*[!?.]` Match 0+ times any char except the listed using [contrast](https://www.rexegg.com/regex-style.html#contrast), then match either `!` `?` `.`
- `)` Close lookahead
- `(\w+:)` Capture group 1, match 1+ word chars and a colon
- `(.*)` Capture group 2, match any char except a newline 0+ times
- `$` End of string

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/wOnHIs/1)

For the second part, if you want a match only for `Choose:`, you could use the negative lookahead only without a capturing group.

```
^(?![^!?.\n\r]*[!?.])\w+:
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/04NKe7/1)